# Setting Redmine path

Tags: reverse-proxy, url, redmine

How can I set the path on which Redmine should be run, e.g. `example.com:3000/redmine` instead of `example.com:3000`? There is an appropriately named option in the settings panel, but it serves a different purpose, according to the documentation and experimental observations (it is used to write URL in emails sent to users).

A wider picture: I need this in order to properly serve Redmine on port 80 over Apache's mod_proxy (i.e. at `example.com/redmine`). The problem is that when running it on `/`, the home page fails to load the necessary resources (such as JavaScript and CSS files). Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made use of the Proxy-HTML module:

```
    ProxyPass /redmine http://example.com:3000
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://example.com:3000 /redmine
    <Location /redmine>
        ProxyPassReverse http://example.com:3000
        SetOutputFilter proxy-html
        ProxyHTMLURLMap /               /redmine/
        ProxyHTMLURLMap /redmine/       /redmine
    </Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

The usage of output filters is actually a bad idea, as I can't work everywhere.

A better idea would be to instruct your app-server (mongrel, thin, whatever) to tell Rails the base URL where the app is deployed. That way, Rails can directly generate the correct links. This can be done by appending `--prefix /redmine` to the app-server parameters.

In the `cluster.xml` file used by mongrel_cluster, the same can be accomplished by inserting

```
prefix: /redmine
```

into it. (at least, I believe this syntax is correct)